# Stuck with playlist on totem 3.10.1

Tags: video, totem

I have 2 systems, both running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and totem 3.10.1. On one of the systems the sidebar (when active) always shows the play-list which I could do without. The other shows some media info about the file being played like duration, resolution, title, etc which I prefer. How can I reset totem to show me the information I want rather than the playlist I don't want. Trying to toggle the play-list does not have the desired effect as it appears it's not a toggle. All I can do is turn the sidebar on and off completely (not what I want). I've reviewed the information on the [totem website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos) and scanned the questions regarding totem here but I couldn't find anything related to my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is simple. Selecting Movie-> Properties puts the desired info back on the sidebar and then totem stays that way upon opening the next movie until you request the playlist again.

See below:

[image]